# Translating using Matrix Android

Tags: android, android-layout, random

I am trying to translate a image using matrix my code is

```
Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.calednder_c);

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

matrix.setTranslate(500,300 );
Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImg, 0, 0, myImg.getWidth(), myImg.getHeight(),
        matrix, true);

circle.setImageBitmap(rotated);
```

when i am calling my animate method nothing happening .while i wrote `preRotate(angle);` it rotate and it scale also but not translate why what i am missing

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is the respective snippet from the `createBitmap` source code:

```
final boolean transformed = !m.rectStaysRect();

RectF deviceR = new RectF();
m.mapRect(deviceR, dstR);

neww = Math.round(deviceR.width());
newh = Math.round(deviceR.height());

bitmap = createBitmap(neww, newh, transformed ? Config.ARGB_8888 : newConfig,
        transformed || source.hasAlpha());

canvas.translate(-deviceR.left, -deviceR.top);
canvas.concat(m);

paint = new Paint();
paint.setFilterBitmap(filter);
if (transformed) {
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
}
```

It makes the created bitmap just big enough to hold all the desired pixels from the original bitmap. This is caused by the new size and the `canvas.translate` call.

The net effect is that translations in the matrix are ignored.